# Is it possible to set privacy setting for our app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Consider that we have a app with custom URL support and any other app which access our app. In such a case can we have any privacy settings kind of similar to if we try to access Contacts from our app?

Comment: Just write html file for Privacy in your app and display in UIWebview.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD: I think this question is about a nice dialog box that says "Should this app be allowed to call into that other app?" and have iOS remember the choices for each app individually.

Comment: I suppose you could implement this yourself (in your own app) if there is a way to find out which app requested the URL (don't know if there is).

Comment: Thanks Thilo, u got my question correctly. How could I give a alert in the app requesting access to my app?

Comment: Probably you'd have to have the alert in your own app.